# Use of Function class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, class

I have seen usage like `var f1=new Function();` but no more than that. Tried to search in Google regarding `Function`-class but nothing returned what I needed.

What is its significance?

Please suggest me **how and when** to use it. If possible give me some genuine link to study about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice suggest you should never use a base type constructor functions. In a lot of case, use `new` with a base type will break the usage of `typeof`.

But, `new Function()` *is valid* JavaScript. Just not recommended, and not useful in most cases (`var a= function() {}` is equivalent).

Not that you can use the `Function` constructor as an `eval` call like so `new Function('var a = 1; return a + a;')`. But this can be dangerous, so use carefully.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Agreed. That's why I added the note on the `eval` capacity.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I actually needed this one.

Comment: can I define the function `f1` after declaring it as: `var f1=new Function();` i.e. I want to define it later than declaring it with `Function` constructor. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: In the same scope you can't overwrite a variable assignement with a function definition. You'd need to remove the variable assignement first.

Comment: simon, Thanx for the supporting fact.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily a beneficial reason to use `new Function()` since you could simply create a blank function like so:

```
var f1 = function () { 
   // my function code here;
};

// calling the function
f1();
```

Each one will have the prototypes of `Function` attached to it either way.

`new Function()` (also `new Array()`, etc) should typically be avoided since it has to eval.

Comment: So is it a valid usage?

Comment: If valid please give a sample code to demonstrate the usage of it. That is what I actually needed.

Comment: var myObject = new f1(); (according to mcp's example)

Comment: Using that syntax how can I define a function. Would you please elaborate that in your answer???

Comment: They're not exactly equivalent; if you use a function expression like in your example, it will close over the outer scope, but `new Function()` won't.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there really isn't a difference between these two bits of JavaScript (other answers have covered this):

```
var f1 = new Function();
```

and

```
var f1 = function () { };
```

What you *can* do, however, is use `Function` to check against the types of your variables:

```
var f1 = 'cat';
console.log(typeof(f1) === typeof(Function)); // false

var f2 = function () { return 'cat'; };
console.log(typeof(f2) === typeof(Function)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

> Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a function and calling it within your code, because functions declared with the function statement are parsed with the rest of the code.

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)